# LaTeX in intelliJ

Tags: compiling, editors, ide, texify-idea

I have installed the idea-latex plug-in in my IntelliJ IDEA. I have created a LaTeX file (but I have found no way to create a LaTeX project!). Some highlighting features work but I cannot find how to generate a .pdf version?

Comment: Any explanation why you think that it's "off the topic" and you put "on hold", while it is about using the LaTeX?

Comment: May be a mistake. I assume this is analogous to TeXlipse in Eclipse, so it would be as on-topic as any other editor.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. , thnxxx a lot. I was trying to use IntelliJ IDEA to synchronize my LaTeX documents with version control systems, as GitHub. But seems that I have to find another alternative...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The readme of `idea-latex` (https://github.com/hsz/idea-latex) currently lists *generating PDF files* under *feature requests*. As such it would appear that at the moment it is not possible to compile documents directly from IntelliJ IDEA with this plugin.

Therefore, your options are I guess either

- using a terminal/command prompt to compile the document, or
- use a different editor. A list of options can be found in [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339).

Answer (score 8):

I just found and used this project:

https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA

Still in alpha, but workable.

Comment: Currently, that's the best option available. 

They already have a stable release and among the many features offered, pdf generation is one of them.

Comment: Actually, I am still using it without problems.

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ has excellent support for the Gradle build system. A suitable, albeit yet spartan, plugin for LaTeX is located at https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/de.steffensky.latex . Use the following buildscript to get started:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.de.steffensky:latex-gradle-plugin:0.2.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: "de.steffensky.latex"

group 'at.ac.uibk.cl-informatik'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

latex {
    documentBase = 'thesis'
    jobname = 'latex'
    pdflatexargs = []
    cookDir = 'out'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the Shell Script mentioned in this Github project, however it's written in German.

https://github.com/dhd80/FOM-LaTeX-Template

Versions and Folders

- Compiletool.sh in Root > here you need arara build tool and xelatex
  https://github.com/cereda/arara

  - Tools/compiletool.sh > is more
    versatile pdflatex without arara
  - Tools/compiletool.bat > .bat

Instructions:

- get the compiletool.sh script from the repository above
- add the script to your IntelliJ project
- within IntelliJ go to: Tools > External Tools (Menu bar)
- hit plus in the new window
- now you need to fill in three text fields:

  - “Name”: give it a Name
  - “Program”: add a path to compiletool.sh
  - “Working directory”: here your pdf will be created, e.g. add the same path as above
- now you are able to compile the pdf from Tools > External Tools

I hope this helps, feel free to add questions.

Comment: Presumably, you're the author of that script? Why not just give the instructions here straight? And in English?

Comment: @Troy your right, please see the edited comment above